# JavaScript keyListener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a keylistener to my input field but I can't make it work. My input type is `text` with `id= "code"`. Here is what I tried:

```
document.querySelector('code').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    window.alert(key);
});
```

and

```
document.getElementById('code').addEventListener("keydown", dealWithKeyboard, false);

function dealWithKeyboard(e) {
    if (window.event) { // IE
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    } else if (e.which) { // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        keynum = e.which;
    }
    window.alert(keynum);
}
```

and

```
document.getElementById('code').onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (window.event) { // IE
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    } else if (e.which) { // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        keynum = e.which;
    }
    window.alert(keynum);
}
```

But none seems to work

Comment: `document.getElementById('code')` will also work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using the proper selector with `document.querySelector()`.  An id value must be preceded by `#` as in `document.querySelector('#code')`.

```
document.querySelector('#code').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    console.log(key);
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
document.querySelector('#code').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  log(key);
});

// show output
function log(x) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = x;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
Type some characters in the Input field here: 
<input id="code">
```

Implemented properly, your `document.getElementById('code')` example should work.

---

**If this still doesn't work, then check for two more things:**

1. Make sure that you are executing this script AFTER the relevant parts of the DOM have been loaded.  There are several ways to assure this, but the simplest is to just located the `<script>` tag after the HTML that it refers to.
2. Make sure that there are no script errors that are preventing your code from executing.  You can check the debug console to check for errors.

Comment: @Ann - Then perhaps you are attempting to run your code too early BEFORE the DOM has loaded.  Make sure the script is in a `<script>` tag that is located AFTER the HTML that it is referring to.  See this answer for more explanation on the timing issue: [How to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701)

Comment: @Ann - Another possibility is that you have a script error that is preventing your code from executing.  You would have to check the debug console to see if you have any such script errors.  As you can see in the snippet above, the concept works just fine when implemented properly.